# Cannot dynamically insert image into Word document

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, officewriter

We are using OfficeWriter 8.6.0 with SSRS 2008 R2 to generate Word documents from .rdl's.

The Word docs being generated are in Office 2003 format (.doc)

The .rdl's were created in VS2008, and then edited in Word via the OfficeWriter add-in. The .rdl's are deployed to the Reporting website, and a program runs the report and saves the resulting byte[] as a Word document.

This process is working fine, however there is now a request to change the documents to include a logo in the header. The logo will be retrieved from a table in a database at runtime, as there are multiple logos of which one is chosen based on an existing report parameter.

The images are .gifs which are stored in a `varbinary(max)` column.

I have followed the method shown on the  [SoftArtisan's wiki page](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/WW8/Inserting+an+Image), in the **Using the Image Modifier** section (without the optional size args) but when the document is generated, no image appears in the header.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Do you get any type of error? Could you also test the modifier not in the header, but in the body of the document. It is possible word template does not process the header for image markers. It has been a while since I have worked with Word Template so I am just speculating.

Comment: @SamPlusPlus no error. Word doc generates fine, but the image doesn't appear. Good suggestion about trying it in the body; I'll try that and post the results.

Comment: @SamPlusPlus Sorry, I haven't had the opportunity yet. I'm the only dev in the office atm and have had to work on other things. Hopefully get a crack at it by the end of the week.